# chrome.tabs.onUpdated tab info returns previous tab title

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to get the title of the tab every time the tab is updated.

As far as I have observed, it works as I want on websites that do server-side routing. However, in client-side routing websites like YouTube, Instagram the result I want comes when the tab is updated for the second time.

For example, when I go in to YouTube, I can get 'YouTube' title, it's OK. When I click on a video, tab.url is changed correctly, but the tab.title is still 'YouTube'. The thing I don't understand is that when I get back from the video to YouTube main page or refresh current video, expected video tab title comes up.

Example background script results in YouTube:

```
https://www.youtube.com/ YouTube (when i go to the youtube)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<id> YouTube (it's still YouTube when i click video)

//if i refresh the page or go back to previous page
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<id> Title of the video - Youtube
```

What i expected when im going to YouTube and click random video?

```
https://www.youtube.com/ YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<id> Title of the video - YouTube
```

Here is my code

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
     if (tab.url !== undefined && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
        console.log(tab.url, tab.title);
    };
});
```

Comment: `chrome.tabs` returns `undefined` for me, is there any code that's supposed to run before? Aside from that, the page title is updating correctly for me when I navigate to a video without needing to refresh (might be misunderstanding here)

Comment: the tab is updating correctly, there is no problem with that. tab.title does not give a correct result as above in my situation.

Comment: Simply replace the entire condition inside `if` with `changeInfo.title`

Comment: nothing changed.

Comment: Since it works for me you probably didn't reload the extension or you didn't remove the check for status?

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Have you tried in youtube like my example ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried again. It works, thanks @wOxxOm.